# Splitting a single Core Data object across multiple UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I’ve got a Core Data object called Drug, which contains 4 attributes; drugEnabled, drugName, drugAdmin, drugExpire.

The Core Data object is pre-populated via parsing a JSON file, so that a single entry might look like this; “drugName": “Drug 1", “drugEnabled": true, “drugAdmin": "1/1/90", “drugExpire": “1/1/00"

The single section table has 3 prototype cells. The first one is for the drug name, and also contains a switch which will be used to hide or show the two cells following, which are used for drugAdmin and drugExpire respectively. The premise being that only the drugs that are enabled (switched on) will display their respective Admin and Expire dates. All disabled drugName cells will be displayed without any respective dates underneath. I can represent this textually the following way:

```
- Drug 1 (on)
- - Drug 1 Admin Date
- - Drug 1 Expire Date
- Drug 2 (on)
- - Drug 2 Admin Date
- - Drug 2 Expire Date
- Drug 3 (off)
- Drug 4 (off)
- Drug 5 (on)
- - Drug 5 Admin Date
- - Drug 5 Expire Date
```

Because I’m not using any sections, and because each object is spread across 3 different rows in the table, I modified the numberOfRowsInSection so that the returned fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count is multiplied by 3, i.e.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] * 3;
}
```

And then I use the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to determine what content belongs in which cell, i.e.

```
- (DrugTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Drug *drug = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellDrug”;
    DrugTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.drugName.text = drug.drugName;     
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.row % 3 == 1) {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellAdmin";
    DrugTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.drugAdmin.text = drug.drugAdmin;       
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.row % 3 == 2) {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellExpire";
    DrugTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.drugExpire.text = drug.drugExpire;     
        return cell;
    }

    else {
        // never returned
        return cell;
    }
}
```

For sake of completeness, I set up the cell heights with the following as well;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row % 3 == 0) {
        return 48;
    }

    else if (indexPath.row % 3 == 1) {
        return 38;
    }

    else if (indexPath.row % 3 == 2) {
        return 38;
    }

    else {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

The error I’m running into is that in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method - as best as I can determine - the number of objects returned by Core Data does not match the number of rows that are in my UITableView. Essentially, I’m taking 5 Core Data objects and splitting them up across 15 different UITableViewCells. Depending on when I instantiate my Drug object, I either get `[_PFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (5) beyond bounds (5)` or I get `no object at index 6 in section at index 0` as my error. I understand the error, however I’m lost as to how to address it.

Again, the main premise behind this table is to be able to hide and show associated rows via a switch, and to do it in a single section table. I haven’t been able to find any examples demystifying this, and I think I’m pretty close, but this error has got me pinched. Has anyone seen any good tutorials/suggestions on displaying a single section table so that the user can hide and show rows based on different criteria?

Comment: The problems is:     Drug *drug = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];    you get another drug when you have to get only a new drug after 3 indexpath.

Comment: From your description it seems like the numbering assumptions in the code are wrong. Five objects only translate to 15 rows if all 5 are "on", and likewise the `% 3` doesn't work if any of the entries are "off". For example in your textual representation, you have 5 drugs but only 11 rows.

Comment: Tom, you are correct in that if any of the 5 entries are 'off' then you would no longer have 15 rows (3x5), which is part of the challenge I'm trying to wrap my head around. Mundi had a good suggestion regarding coalescing the cells together as "closed" and "expanded", but I'm not sure that's going to change a significant part of the challenges with the code. I suppose an alternative would be to not hide them at all and instead simply disable them and perhaps change their content to something like "n/a"

Comment: Having exactly 5 cells when you have 5 objects in the backend will significantly change the challenges with the code. Because there are basically no more challenges left. You just have to save all indexPaths of the drugs that are expanded in an array. Or you could put that state into Core Data as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix indexPath.row (since you are returning count * 3) before calling

```
Drug *drug = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]
```

So you will need to create a new indexPath that is something along the lines of

```
NSIndexPath *adjustedIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row / 3 inSection:indexPath.section];
Drug *drug = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:adjustedIndexPath];
```

Comment: Taylor, your adjustedIndexPath premise seems to do the trick perfectly, although Mundi makes a really good point on it's growing complexity. Many thanks to both of you with the awesome-ly fast response pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

If some cells are going to be open (resulting in one more cell) and others closed (resulting in 3 more cells), the index path calculations are going to be pretty complex. Just working with modulo 3 from `indexPath.row` will not cut it.

Another solution would be perhaps to coalesce the three cells into one. You would only need two cell types, "closed" and "expanded". Then you would not have to think about the index path arithmetic of the `NSFetchedResultsController` any more.

You anyway need to keep track of which cells are open and with are expanded. You just need to account for that in two places, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Mundi, the insight Taylor provided seems to do the trick although you make a great point on it's growing complexity. I still haven't tackled the hiding and showing rows issue and it's associated updates to Core Data. So we'll see just how crazy this concept gets. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: Tylors formula will work only if all rows are "open". This is not what you want.